# Using StringArrayProperty in neo4django

Tags: django, model, filter, neo4j, neo4django

**EDIT** 
I re-writed the question including more general aspects.

I'm using StringArrayProperty in neo4django, using `use_string = True`
so it's saved a single string in Neo4j.

When a new model is created, that field type is a tuple, but I need it as a list.
So this is my approach, when updating the field:

```
self.mystringarray=list(self.mystringarray)
```

Now the problem is:
How can one search in fields like that one?
The NodeModelManager.filter doesn't seem to work on such a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the __member field lookup, which is exactly what I was looking for.